# Incorrect CPU clock speed?

Tags: ati, cpu

I have recently purchased a new laptop, and installed Ubuntu. It uses an AMD A8-4500M processor, which, according to the link below, should have a clock speed of 1900-2800 mhz.

http://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-A-Series-A8-4500M-Notebook-Processor.74884.0.html

When I use the "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep name" command, it says the cpu speed is only 1400mhz. Could someone please explain why this is?

Thanks

```
jimmy@jimmy-Lenovo-G505s:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep name
model name  : AMD A8-4500M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
model name  : AMD A8-4500M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics   
model name  : AMD A8-4500M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics   
model name  : AMD A8-4500M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics   
jimmy@jimmy-Lenovo-G505s:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1   
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            21
Model:                 16
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               1400.000
BogoMIPS:              3792.81
Virtualisation:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             16K
L1i cache:             64K
L2 cache:              2048K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your processor is capable of switching between different clock speeds. When it has not much to do it runs on 1400 MHz therefore saving energy which gives you a longer battery life.

When you give the processor a lot of work it wil automatically switch to it's highest clockspeed :-)

A nice article about that is here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_Frequency_Scaling